# Why don't single row circuits work on a breadboard?

Tags: led, breadboard

I am fairly new to electronics, and whilst messing around with a simple LED circuit on my breadboard I noticed that when connect my resistor and LED on two separate rows, the LED lights up as it expected. However when I connect them on the same row, the LED doesn't light up. I tired this other rows and checked all the connections to see if there was a problem. Can someone please explain to me why the LED doesn't light up when I try to connect everything up on the same row?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to check with DMM how the holes are connected on your breadboard?

Comment: You should read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard) and the specification of the breadboard you use. You should know how the holes of the breadboard are connected before using it.

Comment: reverse your thinking .... ask instead "Why does the LED light up in the first picture?"

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone please explain to me why the LED doesn't light up when I try to connect everything up on the same row?

Because you have shorted out the pins by connecting them to each other via the one socket strip line in the breadboard.

[image]

*Figure 1. The faint red lines indicate the connected breadboard sockets. Note that each row has five connected sockets. Source: [Technology Student](http://www.technologystudent.com/elec1/bread1.htm).*

To power any electrical circuit you need a potential difference across its terminals so that current will flow. Connecting them together prevents this and so your LED won't light.

I think that if you think through your thought process you will find that you expected the breadboard row to connect the resistor to the LED but, somehow, not connect one leg of the LED to the other. Would that be right?